# Why isn't my image displaying in my answer?

Tags: discussion, support

When editing [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/15788/which-wireless-keyboard-is-most-secure/15793#15793), the image displays properly in the edit preview.  However, the image doesn't appear in the actual answer.  What is going wrong?

Comment: An image not displaying is the least of your worries, seeing as the question doesn't exist.

Comment: That question is getting up vote also.. How come you are saying that question doesn't exist

Comment: @Pesto - why you are always thinking I am Wrong :-)

Comment: @Kirsh - COnsidering that the question ID changed between the two different links you provided it should answer the question already. I suspect the first link points to the answer and not the question.

Comment: @Kirsh: I'm using Bayesian inference.  And -- surprise, surprise! -- you *were* wrong.  Your original question contained only a link to a deleted answer.  Your edit contains two links, one to the deleted answer, one to the question itself, neither of which are applicable.  I've edited it to actually include the answer under discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the image is protected from hotlinking by referrer checking, or unusual characters in the URL.

Easy way to test for and fix both: move the image to a free image hosting service and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The image URL works fine if you go there directly, but it doesn't appear in either the answer or the edit list.  I'd guess that the image is protected against hotlinking.

Comment: That certainly does seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been deleted. Most likely why you got the problem.

Comment: Question is still alive :-)

Comment: I answered when you only had the first link which points only to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's the underscore in the URL that makes it fail.

---

Update: It's working for me now.